# Writing a panel for RViz in Python / accessing RosTopicHz from C++

Tags: ros, python, c++, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I would like to write a RViz panel where I can see the actual publishing rate on a given topic (same thing I can do with "rostopic hz" from command line).

I have seen in the tutorial that panels for RViz are written in C++ and the class *ROSTopicHz* is written in Python.

Is there any way to access the class to get the actual publishing rate based on a given topic name from C++?

I could implement the functionality from *ROSTopicHz* in C++ but the problem I am facing is that I won't know prior which topics and message types I will subscribe to (this should be selectable during runtime). So I would need a way to dynamically create subscriber objects and callback functions in C++.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this or a way to write a panel for RViz in Python directly?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287851/writing-a-panel-for-rviz-in-python-/-accessing-rostopichz-from-c++/) by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without (quite) some trickery, writing RViz panels in Python is probably going to be difficult.

Dynamically subscribing to topics can be done both in Python as well as in C++ though, I don't immediately see why that would be any more difficult. Almost all RViz display plugins and quite some Panel plugins do it. See [rviz/default_plugin/marker_display.cpp](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/82fe57aa42228eed9dff439937050b4420e07ba9/src/rviz/default_plugin/marker_display.cpp#L147-L171) for instance.

---

It would be somewhat involved, but one way to get this info into RViz could be to write a Python publisher that wraps `rostopic.ROSTopicHz`, publishes the data you're after and then write a regular C++ panel plugin (something like [InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rviz_plugin](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/simple_rviz_plugin)) to display it inside RViz.

If you don't absolutely need it to be an RViz panel, you could perhaps take a look at [rqt_topic](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_topic), which shows the same statistics (and more), but is an `rqt` plugin. RQT can also host an RViz instance.

---

Edit:

> Thank you for your great answer! The problem I am seeing with C++ is that I need to create callback functions on runtime for new subscribers (so I can distinguish them for measuring publishing rate) because the messages have different types. I don't know at compile time the message types.

The `topic_tools` pkg also has a C++ side to it. That provides the [ShapeShifter](http://docs.ros.org/api/topic_tools/html/classtopic__tools_1_1ShapeShifter.html) class, which allows you to subscribe to any topic at runtime. See also [ros_type_introspection/Tutorials/GenericTopicSubscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection/Tutorials/GenericTopicSubscriber).

> To clarify my idea a bit more: I have a system with quite many devices (all of them are publishing data in ROS) and several people are working on the system. Sometimes one or two devices are not running (because somene forgot to plug in a cable again for example). Since we don't have a mechanism to track these problems down with the nodes directly (legacy code problems) we just check with rostopic hz if there is data on the desired topics. So the panel should be reconfigurable to measure the publishing rate on all types of topics.

I should've asked you *why* you wanted to this, but reading this description makes me wonder whether we're not solving an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info).

What you're describing sounds more like a task for [diagnostics](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
Thank you for your great answer! The problem I am seeing with C++ is that I need to create callback functions on runtime for new subscribers (so I can distinguish them for measuring publishing rate) because the messages have different types.  I don't know at compile time the message types.

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
I have thought about using a template function but how can I detect which topic I am getting the callback function call from at the moment? Thank you very much for your help!

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
To clarify my idea a bit more: I have a system with quite many devices (all of them are publishing data in ROS) and several people are working on the system. Sometimes one or two devices are not running (because somene forgot to plug in a cable again for example). 1-2

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
2-2 Since we don't have a mechanism to track these problems down with the nodes directly (legacy code problems) we just check with *rostopic hz* if there is data on the desired topics. So the panel should be reconfigurable to measure the publishing rate on all types of topics.

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
I don't think it was a xy-problem. I just didn't know about the GenericTopicSubscriber. The panel will meet all our requirements in the current project status.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
Slightly pedantic, but: you seem to be after a way to monitor the status of various topics (or really: the status of various nodes). You picked something that you believe could be a viable approach: monitoring publications using `ROSTopicHz`. The problem is that it's a Python class, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
.. and you want to write an RViz panel (another approach you've already selected). Now the issue is that Python and RViz panels are not compatible, so you ask a question about your already selected (and implicit until your last comment) solution, instead of the real problem. That would seem to ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
.. have the characteristics of an xy-problem.

I don't mind at all really, but thought it was good to mention it.

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-08**:
I was not sure if there is a way to write a panel in Python so I asked this question. I know that writing a rqt plugin in Python would be way easier but I this was not an option (my task is to write a panel for RViz directly). I should have mentioned that I has to be in RViz - sorry for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
You don't need to apologise for anything, as I already wrote, my last comment was pedantic.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-04-08**:
Also see: http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics which lets you get statistics without directly subscribing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
That would certainly make things a lot easier. I should've mentioned that. Now @ce_guy would only need to create a panel that visualises those msgs. See [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph) for an example of how rqt graph annotates the node graph with that info.

**Comment by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on 2018-04-09**:
Great info, I didn‘t know about that. Thank you very much guys!